# Generate sequence of 0s and 1s such that the probability of one is 0.3 after any trial

Tags: matlab, probability

I am trying to generate a random sequence of 0s and 1s such that any time a sequence is generated, the probability of 1 is 0.3. I tried the following in Matlab

```
%%clear all; %%close all;clc; %%(rand(1,10)<=0.3)
```

The problem is that every time I run this, I get a different proportion of 1s.
Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: I tried using the randi function but everytime i get diff no. of ones in the sequence

Comment: You should probably show the code and explain the problem with it better to get some guidance here.

Comment: %%clear all;
%%close all;clc;
%%(rand(1,10)<=0.3)

Comment: i tried more

n = 1e5;
x = (rand(1,n)<=0.3);
sum(x) / n

ans =

    0.3012

Comment: What do you mean by "simpler"? Do you want the proportion of 1's to exactly 0.3? That is not possible. If you have any sequence of 1's and 0's, then it is always possible to find a sub-sequence for which the proportion of 1's is not equal to 0.3. However, using the code you entered above, the proportion of 1's will get closer and closer to 0.3 as `n` becomes larger.

Comment: @cjh I assume that "any time" means "for every run", not "for every sub-sequence of the sequence".

Comment: @Mathias, ahhh, that makes sense. However, in this case, if the 1's and 0's are presented as a sequence then the sequence is not truly random, because the final element of the sequence can be known based on the preceding elements.

Comment: @cjh agreed with your statement; observations in that sequence are certainly not independent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have *exactely* a propotion of 0.3 at the end, you can do:

```
n=1000; %should be a multiple of 10.
x=[ones(1,n*3/10) zeros(1,n*7/10)];
x=x(randperm(n));
```

Basically, it creates an array with a `0.3` proportion of `1`.

Then, it permutes it randomly.

Comment: Not familiar enough with Matlab, but assuming randperm is a shuffle, this approach is correct: create a sequence containing 30% of 1s and 70% of 0s, and shuffle it.

Comment: In this case you get the precise proportion to be 0.3, but the final element of the sequence will always be a deterministic function of the preceding elements. More generally, if the data are presented sequentially, then the probability of the n-th element being "1" is a function of the values of the n-1 preceding elements.

Comment: @cjh, Yes, You're totally right. I think that what the OP really want is what he wrote in the question: `x=(rand(1,n)<=0.3)`. However, he was complaining about the fact that he gets 0.3012 in the end, so I thought that the `randperm` solution could help him to get precisely 0.3

Comment: Worth noting that this obviously isn't guaranteed to have that proportion at any point in the list, only at the end---I can't determine from the question which is required

Comment: Thanks guys! I could have the solution through rand perm and OLI is right with using the rand function!!!